# Flycheck + shellcheck: always use new temporary frame, not modeline

Tags: flycheck

I have been using both flycheck and shellcheck for just under a week under emacs 24.5.1.  They work fine in principle.

I have a question though regarding flycheck's choice to simply use the modeline vs. using a new temporary subframe (in the current frame, at the bottom, in my case) to display its warnings/errors.

It occurs to me (cross checking with cli shellcheck output on the same source file) that flycheck is creating the above mentioned ephemeral frame for multi-line warnings/errors **that occur on the same column**, while using the modeline for all other warnings/errors.

I would like to configure it to *always* use an ephemeral frame, but can't seem to find out how. Anyone can help out?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>!</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> will run `flycheck-list-errors`, giving you a frame containing the buffer `*Flycheck errors*`, based on your starting buffer. To get the error list for every file you open, you can add `flycheck-list-errors` to `find-file-hook`, although you'll probably want to restrict what files that occurs with, and have greater control of the error frame.

Personally, I have `flycheck` enabled (almost) globally, and only open the error list on demand. It's easy enough for me to ignore `flycheck` when the error list is closed.